# Why are the files from the Google libraries api loaded via HTTPS

Tags: api

Well the main question says it all, why are the files loaded via https. I am just adding some new libraries to the website, and noticed that the links are all https://.

Now from what I understand you use https when there is some sensitive information, and I do not think that is the case with these libraries I guess. I think nobody is interested in getting the content of these files.

Is there any explanation for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People [asked for it](http://googleajaxsearchapi.blogspot.com/2008/07/ajax-libraries-ssl-support-is-live.html) so they could use the libraries on things like e-commerce sites, which eventually require an SSL connection. They provide links to the https version by default to make it easier for everyone overall (automatically avoids mixed-content warnings), and for most people the slight performance cost won't matter. But if you know you won't have any need for it, just strip it down to a regular http connection:

- https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
- http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

They did actually publish the http URLs at one point, but I'd imagine that the resulting mixed-content warnings etc that came about as a result of people adding SSL connections and not thinking it through just created a bunch of support questions, so it was simpler to default to showing https and let people hack it if they really wanted.

Comment: Someday I hope non-encrypted HTTP goes the way of gopher.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, didn;t think of people actually using an SSL site.